# Received a job offer but HR not responding

Tags: recruitment

I have received verbal offer as well as an electronic offer letter where I agreed to the offer from a very large corporation and they took my passport information and said they were processing the documents to begin the on boarding process.

It has been a couple of weeks since then and I have sent multiple emails and they do not respond.  I also don't have there phone number so I cannot contact them verbally.

Should I take an further action? Is it safe to assume that the offer is still on the table?

Also do you think it's appropriate if I contact the recruiter by getting there phone number from an internal employee that I know even if it was not given to me?

**Update:** I managed to get a hold of the HR via telephone and it seems like people were out of office on business trip and that's why they were not replying to me.

Comment: How did they find you? How did you receive the offer? How did they take your information? I'm sure you can find a phone number for someone in all the communication you had with the company.

Comment: Well I formally applied through their website so they had all my contact information.  They called me up told me they had an offer and sent me a document which I replied via email that I accepted the offer.

Comment: @guidingstructures go back to the website where you applied, find the "contact us" section, and call them.

Comment: Did you actually interview with them?  You applied, but what kinds of contacts have you had with them?  Do you know this isn't just a scam to get your passport and other identification information?

Comment: Yes I interviewed them, and I know this is not a scam since it's a reputable big company.  HR, recuiters and hiring manager all in one single email thread.

Comment: Was the interview in person or over the phone? Either way can't you go to the place you interviewed at, or ring the number that called you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Verbal offers are worth the paper they are printed on.**

You've already reached out via email - you need to figure out how to call them.  First look through every email you've received form them and see if one of the employees had a phone number in the signature.  Next look on the website and see if there is a Contact Us phone number.

Finally, you should probably continue or restart your job search.  The offer is probably still on the table, but sometimes offers fall through, and you don't want to have to restart your job search after a month of waiting.

Comment: Do you think it's appropriate if I contact the HR if I get there phone number from an internal employee that I know but that number is not publicly available?

Comment: @guidingstructures No.  Absolutely not.  Go through the proper channels by going on to their website, finding a contact number and calling it.  Ask for the HR/recruiterment person by name on the main line.

Comment: @guidingstructures: That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I would advise against it.  People don't like being surprised, and now is not a good time to rock the boat.

Comment: Get the number from your contact. Google the number. If it shows up on a public web site as the HR number, use it. If it doesn't show up, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to assume that the offer is still on the table?

As the accepted answer has nicely put, **No** it is not safe to assume that the offer is well on the table. I would also advise you to resume your job search. There is nothing to lose here. If the offer is still valid, then well and good, you can end your search and join. Else, you are already in your search.

> Should I take an further action?  Also do you think it's appropriate
>   if I contact the recruiter by getting there phone number from an
>   internal employee that I know even if it was not given to me?

Yes, as it has been some time since any activity from their side, it is always good to push them. So, it's completely appropriate to get the contact number of the recruiter from an internal employee. This would help you getting the air cleared on the offer.